# C# how to sort user input from textbox in ascending order

Tags: c#, string, winforms, sorting, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to allow a user to enter ten alphanumeric values into 10 textboxes in ascending order. Once the values are entered I want to use any sorting algorithm to check if the values have been sorted correctly so I can display a message to the user that their ordering was either correct or incorrect. I'm not sure how I can implement this.

the code below is my list of strings that display in random to the user

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        var list = new List<string> { "12fe", "46ge", "7uf", "15gs", "64ku", "42nt", "04bv", "07nh", "03lf", "86nj" };
        var random = new Random();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           
            int index = random.Next(list.Count);
            listBox1.Items.Add(list[index]);
        }
```

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

[here is my Listbox that generates random strings and my textboxes for the user to enter them in ascending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugXex.png)

Comment: You can use `OrderBy` -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0

Comment: You need to remove the items from the List as you add them to the listbox

Comment: The posted code appears to have absolutely nothing to do with the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***OrderBy*** by to sort the list item and use ***SequenceEqual*** to compare two list order.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<string> { "12fe", "46ge", "7uf", "15gs", "64ku", "42nt", "04bv", "07nh", "03lf", "86nj"};
    var orderedList = list.OrderBy(i => i);
    MessageBox.Show(orderedList.SequenceEqual(list).ToString());            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use .Sort() ?

```
var list = new List<string> { "12fe", "46ge", "7uf", "15gs", "64ku", "42nt", "04bv", "07nh", "03lf", "86nj" };
list.Sort();
```

and after place your listBox1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a special button to check the order; This is what I did and this is the result where the order is compared and shown in the MessageBox as you indicated in your question with icons added for greater clarity by the MessageBox rating

I did a program to make sure and this is the picture:
[The result of program to check ascending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMrsf.png)

And this is the code I used to read the contents of list box and then compare from the list to check if it is ascending order

```
        private void sort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> { };

        foreach (string temp in listBox1.Items)
        {
            list.Add(temp);
        }
        var ascending_order = list.OrderBy(item => item);
        if (ascending_order.SequenceEqual(list))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The ordering of the list is correct", "Sort result",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The ordering of the list is Incorrect", "Sort result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

This is my first answer on this site (stackoverflow)!

Comment: thanks for the answer,however i want the answers entered in the 10 textboxes to be checked if they are in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

In your sort button click, take all the 10 texts and put them in an array

```
var a = new [] {
  textbox1.Text,
  textbox2.Text,
  textbox3.Text,
  ...
  textbox10.Text
};
```

Now you can sort them using some common LINQ sorting:

```
var sorted = a.ToList().Sort();
```

Now you can cehck if they're in the same order with sequenceequal:

```
var isSame = sorted.SequenceEquals(a);
```

If this is an academic exercise and you're not expected to use things like LINQ, i suggest you look at making your own sort (bubblesort is an easy algo to write) and your own version of sequenceEqual (use a for loop to step through the two lists checking if the elements are the same)

Bear in mind that by default in C# sorting is case sensitive