# How to check if strings in textboxes are in ascending order

Tags: c#, string, winforms

i have an application that generates 10 random strings then i require the user to enter these 10 strings into 10 textboxes in ascending order, once this is done the user clicks a button that checks if the order is correct then gives them a message if it was correct or not.

THE ISSUE: when a user enters every value generated in my list box to the 10 ten textboxes REGARDLESS OF ORDER and clicks the check button, success message displays. This shouldn't happen since the user only entered the values present in the listbox and did not enter them in ascending order. However if the user enters in a wrong value that's not in the listbox then the failure message is shown.The failure message should be shown aswell if the order was not in ascending.

[The first image shows the strings being placed in ascending order and a success message being shown,Note that the only reason the success message is been showing is because the user entered all the values in the textbox that are present in the list box and not because they are in ascending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npGUg.png)

[In the second image if you look at the first two textboxes you will see that the first value and second value have been swapped.This means the values entered are no longer in ascending order and therefore the failure message should be shown however the application is not checking if the values are sorted correctly and is still displaying the success message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pzk3.png)

[The last picture shows that if a value which doesn't exist in the list box is entered in any of the texboxes,a failure message will display.This supposed to happen however the failure message should also appear if the order was not in ascending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1QG6.png)

```
   public static List<string> values = new List<string> { "001.45 EBC", "004.56 VWH", "002.44 MFH", "003.88 CSK", "006.96 FEB", "008.77 NJC", "005.23 MKF", "007.62 IJN", "010.13 FNH", "009.88 ENC" };//list of call numbers created
    public ReplaceBooksPage() //replace  books class
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //generate button created
    {


     listBox1.Items.Clear();//clears items in the list box

    var random = new Random(); //random class created

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {//for loop created that adds 10 random numbers to listbox
 
     int index = random.Next(values.Count); 
    listBox1.Items.Add(values[index]);//adds items to listbox
```

}

```
    }
   private void btn_sort(object sender, EventArgs e)//generate button created
    {
          List<string> list2 = new List<string>();//list created
    var list = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
        list.Sort();//sorts he list

        list2.Add(textBox1.Text); //adds each textbox to the list
        list2.Add(textBox2.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox3.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox4.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox5.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox6.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox7.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox8.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox9.Text);
        list2.Add(textBox10.Text);
        list2.Sort();
        if (list.SequenceEqual(list2))//if statment created
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sucess"); //disaplays a message to the user if the ordering was correct
        }
        else //else statement
        {
            MessageBox.Show("fail"); //displays a message to the user if the ordering was incorrect
        }
    }
```

Comment: `list2.Sort()`: this sorts the entered values, so you compare then two already sorted lists. I think you want to remove this line.

Comment: Yes however no matter what order or value i enter, it allways fails when i remove list2.sort()

Comment: This is the third question on the same topic within 2/3 days here on SO!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# how to sort user input from textbox in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69371536/c-sharp-how-to-sort-user-input-from-textbox-in-ascending-order)

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting the list of the users input on the button click, thus it sorts it into the correct order, then when they enter an option that doesnt exist, it wont match up, so then it would not return correct. Do not sort `list2`

Comment: Yes but whe i Dont sort list2 then it allways fails when i enter any value

Answer (score 0):

As people above stated: you must remove `list2.Sort()` if you want this to work as intended. If removing that sort alone causes `False` in the comparison result, then entered strings are **not** equal. See the small example below:

```cs
        var list1 = new string[] { "3 three", "1 one", "2 two" }.ToList();
        var list2 = new string[] { "1 one", "2 two", "3 three" }.ToList();
        
        foreach (var item in list1) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Are lists equal: {list1.SequenceEqual(list2)}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        list1.Sort();
        
        foreach (var item in list1) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Are lists equal: {list1.SequenceEqual(list2)}");
        Console.WriteLine();
```

You might want to see what's actually gathered from the textboxes by printing out the list values:

```cs
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Item {i+1}: '{list2[i]}'");
        }
```

Perhaps you are entering a whitespace in one of the textboxes.
Keep in mind, that `1 one` is not equal to e.g.  `1 one` nor `1 one`  (mind the spaces).

Comment: Note that the second `WriteLine` call outputs the items in the list enclosed by single-quotes. This is an essential part of the output for these types of problems because it will clearly show things like leading or trailing white space, or newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your application code will be as below:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms_ExchangeTextsInTextBoxes
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// list of call numbers created
        /// </summary>
        public static List<string> values = new List<string>
        {
            "001.45 EBC",
            "004.56 VWH",
            "002.44 MFH",
            "003.88 CSK",
            "006.96 FEB",
            "008.77 NJC",
            "005.23 MKF",
            "007.62 IJN",
            "010.13 FNH",
            "009.88 ENC"
        };


        public static List<string> sortedListBoxValues = new List<string> { };

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //clears items in the list box
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            //random class created
            Random random = new Random();

            //for loop created that adds 10 random numbers to listbox
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int index = random.Next(values.Count);

                //adds items to listbox
                listBox1.Items.Add(values[index]);

                // Add values to the sortedList
                sortedListBoxValues.Add(values[index]);
            }

            // Sort sorted list of listBox values
            sortedListBoxValues.Sort();
        }

        private void Btn_Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //list created
            List<string> textBoxValues = new List<string>();

            //adds each textbox to the list
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox1.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox2.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox3.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox4.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox5.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox6.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox7.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox8.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox9.Text);
            textBoxValues.Add(textBox10.Text);

            if (sortedListBoxValues.SequenceEqual(textBoxValues))
            {
                //disaplays a message to the user if the ordering was correct
                MessageBox.Show("sucess");
            }
            else
            {
                //displays a message to the user if the ordering was incorrect
                MessageBox.Show("fail");
            }
        }
    }
}
```